# Keep text at bottom of Visualforce generated PDF page?

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I am generating a PDF with VF. There is a block of text (privacy statement) that needs to go at the bottom of the last page of what could be several pages. It should sit above the footer for that page. How can i tell VF to put the code at the bottom.  When I use 'bottom' on the style statement, nothing happens.??

This is some sample code

span style="font-size:8pt;vertical-align: bottom;  color:#343433;">
To assist us to provide you with services, we need to collect personal and   credit information about you. We may disclose this information to other 
parties (who may be located overseas), including third party providers, and to external agencies as described in our privacy policy, etc
  br/>

Comment: Take a look at https://force201.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/page-headers-and-footers-in-renderaspdf-visualforce-pages/.

Comment: Thanks, but your reference looks like it is talking about page footers.  The text i am referring to needs to sit above the footer which is occupied by the company logo & appears at the bottom of each page. The privacy statement should only appear at the bottom of the last page. It is about 300 or 400 words so not just a one liner. It needs to sit above the company logo footer.

Comment: I think it would help if you had some excerpts of code that show what you are attempting.

Comment: I believe you should be able to use "fixed" positioning.

Comment: edited my question to provide a sample of the text and the VF code.  This puts the text just underneath whatever text went before it rather than at the bottom of the page just above the footer.